# Angular pass index to pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filter, pipe

I'm trying to use the *ngFor index within my pipe as follows:

```
<td *ngFor="let course of courses | matchesTime:time | matchesWeekday:i ; index as i">{{course.courseName}}</td>
```

My pipe looks like this:

```
transform(items: Array<any>, weekday: number): Array<any> {
    return items.filter(
        item => item.weekday === weekday
    );
}
```

But the weekday turns out to be undefined. I believe the index isn't initialized when the pipe does it's processing.

EDIT:
I added a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-pipe-index-error

Answer (score 0):

Try this, see if it inits index

```
<td *ngFor="let course of courses | matchesTime:time | matchesWeekday:i | let i=index">{{course.courseName}}</td>
```

Comment: same result, equals undefined

Comment: try with the pipe, if that doesn't work, I think maybe a wrapper div that sets the index and courses, and then the TD below it with all the pipes etc.

Comment: the pipe doesn't work. Are you thinking about something like this:
<ng-container *ngFor="let course of courses | matchesTime:time; let i = index">
    <td>{{course.courseName| matchesWeekday:i }}</td>
</ng-container>

and the pipe:

transform(item: any, weekday: number): Array<any> {
  if (item.weekday === weekday) {
   return item.courseName
  }
  return;
 }

Because this equals 0 for every weekday somehow...